# How can i use GDI+ to save a HBITMAP

Tags: image, winapi, gdi+, png

I want to save my created image as a PNG or JPEG file with the help of GDI+  but i can't find a way to do this. Seems that there is no way to create a non file based Image and fill it with a bitblit from the HBITMAP.

Or do i miss something?

Comment: Are you having trouble loading the image from HBITMAP, or are you having trouble saving the image to jpg/png?  I can share code for the latter.  Otherwise, Hans suggestion below should jsut work.

Comment: I wasn't looking at the Bitmap subclass. I think FromHBITMAP will work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Bitmap::FromHBITMAP() method.  Then just Save() it.